# Fetch Substring from NSString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsstring, nsrange

I have the following string :

```
Item 1#Item 2#Item 3#Item 4#Item 5#Item 6#Item 7#Item 8#Item 9#Item 10#Item 11#Item 12#Item 13#Item 14#Item 15#
```

I want to extract each Item name. How can it be done?

Comment: You can Use **componentsSeparatedByString:** with NSSting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
NSString *temp = @"Item 1#Item 2#Item 3#Item 4#Item 5#Item 6#Item 7#Item 8#Item 9#Item 10#Item 11#Item 12#Item 13#Item 14#Item 15#";
    NSArray *arr = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Comment: If I understood well, must be `NSArray *arr = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];`.

Answer (score 0):

Separate each string

```
NSString *str = @"Item 1#Item 2#Item 3#Item 4#Item 5#Item 6#Item 7#Item 8#Item 9#Item 10#Item 11#Item 12#Item 13#Item 14#Item 15#";
NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string=@"Item 1#Item 2#Item 3#Item 4#Item 5#Item 6#Item 7#Item 8#Item 9#Item 10#Item 11#Item 12#Item 13#Item 14#Item 15#";

NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]];
```